# TikZ: text color in node different than text=color

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given the following example, how is it possible to change the text color of the word *node* in the first circle without affecting the color of the remaining text inside, i.e., *With*?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[fill=green, text=red, circle, draw=black] {With node};
        \draw[fill=cyan] (3,0) circle (1cm) node[text=blue] {With draw};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could use `\textcolor` inside of the node:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[fill=green, text=red, circle, draw=black] {With
      \textcolor{cyan}{node}};
        \draw[fill=cyan] (3,0) circle (1cm) node[text=blue] {With draw};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]